# Link wrapped around an image click event in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, jquery-events

I need a click event for jQuery so that when someone clicks on an image on my site, it will run the click event and then send them to the destination link from the "a" tag. How would I do this? I assume the click event would be on the link? Maybe not? Here is the link and image

```
<a href="go/to/here" class="link_for_image">
   <img alt="Image!" class="dynamic" width="200" height="200" src="image/path/here">
</a>
```

EDIT

I need to do some Javascript before I send the user to the link. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why you need Javascript?

Comment: as far as I understand from your question, this snippet does exactly what you want; sending the user to the page of the link. So what is your problem?

Comment: Because I need to do some javascript work before the link sends the user to the destination.

Comment: Than you should mention it in your Q

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Since tour image is wrapped inside an anchor tag, when you click on image, it will be considered as a click on the anchor tag.

**EDIT** : From your comment, you want to do some javascript before the actual link works

```
$(function(){
 $(".link_for_image").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var item=$(this);
   //Here you can do what you want on the clik

   window.location.href=item.attr("href");
 });    
});
```

Comment: I can just +1 your answer cause any other approach to that (as far the Q is asked in that manner) seems stupid